# Synonyms for "rather than" (preferably single word synonyms)

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

Example usage:

> A person can reuse their current tool **rather than** purchasing a new tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A person can reuse their current tool **vice** purchasing a new tool.

**vice**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vice)

> prep. In place of; replacing:

from Latin, ablative of vicis: change.

Comment: Does 'in place of' indicate preference as the question specifies?

Comment: @Spagirl my sense is yes